# When criteria is met in a column, check dup value in another column and copy row

Tags: excel, vba

I need vba to search for the word with "new" in the address in column D then when found look for the matches of ages in adjacent column C. Copy the entire row in sheet2.

Sheet1 is the raw data and the answer is in sheet2. New York with age 36 and all age of 36 will be copied. New Jersey with age 21 and all 21 will be copied and so on. Is it also possible that the "new" will be either in the front or end of the word when searching?

Not all the duplicate age in column C will be copied. Just need to check the criteria in column D first before getting the dups. Thanks in advance.

I can't find any same samples codes for this case.

Sample:
Sheet1 - raw data
Age Address
29  Alaska
36  Texas
36  New York
36  New York
45  Alaska
36  Illinois
45  Illinois
29  Alaska
21  Idaho
21  New Jersey
45  New Mexico
20  Idaho
40  California
40  California
20  Florida

Sheet2 - answer
Age Address
36  Texas
36  New York
36  New York
45  Alaska
36  Illinois
45  Illinois
21  Idaho
21  New Jersey
45  New Mexico

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a good question. Show both of your data sheets, and describe what you have tried so far. It's not enough to say "I can't find any same samples codes for this case."

Comment: If you really need some help then please go to this site https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables and make tables with the data and paste them into the question so they can be copied. It would be good if you could also post pictures of the sheets so that someone can easily relate it visually in your words to the cells